# Why my oracle to_date is returning this error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: java, sql, oracle, talend

I'm trying to use java and SQL in talend and I'm getting the following error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Here my java code:

```
Date supply_date_last_filter =  new Date();

Date supply_date_start_filter;

supply_date_last_filter = TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyyyy",TalendDate.formatDate("ddMMyyyy", new Date()));

if (context.work_METI_last_date != null && !"".equals(context.work_METI_last_date)) {
     supply_date_last_filter = TalendDate.parseDate("ddMMyyyy",context.work_METI_last_date);
}

supply_date_start_filter = TalendDate.addDate(supply_date_last_filter, - Integer.parseInt(context.work_METIstore_last_days), "dd");

String supply_date_start_filter_str = TalendDate.formatDate("ddMMyyyy",supply_date_start_filter);

String supply_date_last_filter_str = TalendDate.formatDate("ddMMyyyy",supply_date_last_filter);
```

and here my SQL code which I am using in Talend:

```
"""SELECT substr(fld_znvaleur, 5, 3) store_code, substr(fld_znvaleur, 8, 8) order_number, substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8) order_date, std_cdsitu, std_lbsitu, wcd_tydemand, tyd_lbtypdem
FROM "" + context.link_METIsupply_DB_schema + "".mgfld
INNER JOIN "" + context.link_METIsupply_DB_schema + "".mgfle
    ON (fle_cdflux = fld_cdflux
    AND fle_notrait = fld_notrait)
LEFT JOIN "" + context.link_METIsupply_DB_schema + "".mgwcd
    ON (wcd_nocdemag = to_number(substr(fld_znvaleur, 8, 8))
    AND wcd_noclcash = to_number(substr(fld_znvaleur, 5, 3)))
LEFT JOIN  "" + context.link_METIsupply_DB_schema + "".mgstd
    ON (wcd_tydemand = std_tydemand and wcd_cdetat = std_cdsitu)
LEFT JOIN  "" + context.link_METIsupply_DB_schema + "".mgtyd
    ON (tyd_tydemand = wcd_tydemand)
WHERE fld_cdflux = 'DDE'
  AND fld_cdfichier = 'DDE_E'
  AND substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8) BETWEEN to_date('"" + ((String) globalMap.get(""supply_date_start_filter_str"")) + ""','DDMMYYYY')
    AND to_date('"" + ((String) globalMap.get(""supply_date_last_filter_str"")) + ""','DDMMYYYY')
and substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8) <> '        '
AND substr(fld_znvaleur, 5, 3) in "" + context.work_METIstore_list"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that Oracle couldn't convert the string you gave it into a Date using "DDMMYYYY".

There's 2 possibilities, since some of your code does not use best practices for working with dates:

- Don't compare strings to dates. Wrap `substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8)` in a `to_date()` call.
- `supply_date_start_filter` and `supply_date_last_filter` are Talend Date objects, but you're casting them to String in the SQL query, without specifying a format mask. Why not use the String versions that you created at the end of your Java code?

I would rewrite your code as:

```
AND to_date(substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8),'DDMMYYYY') 
  BETWEEN to_date('"" + ((String) globalMap.get(""supply_date_start_filter_str"")) + ""','DDMMYYYY')
      AND to_date('"" + ((String) globalMap.get(""supply_date_last_filter_str"")) + ""','DDMMYYYY')
```

If that doesn't fix it, you could have unexpected data in your table. See if this query causes the error by itself:

```
select * from mgfld where to_date(substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8),'DDMMYYYY') = sysdate;
```

Edit: You could try this query to find rows in `mgfld` which violate your expectation (8 character substring, all numbers).

```
select * from mgfld where regexp_instr(substr(fld_znvaleur, 16, 8),'^[0-9]{8}$') = 0;
```

Comment: for the str it's just an error of  copy past, I'm trying  your to_date options and i'm coming back to you

Comment: this is the new message that I have tDBInput_3 ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: I added a query to look for invalid rows in the table, see if that helps?